# Why are the p-values for Kendall's Tau of psych::corr.test and cor.test different?

Tags: r, correlation, kendall-tau

I am calculating Kendall's Tau and corresponding p-values for the association between several variables. To correct for multiple comparisons, I am using the corr.test function from the psych package. However, the results from the package are different from the results I get with the cor.test function. Here's a toy example:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9)
z <- c(2:10,1)
alldata = data.frame(x,y,z)

cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$y,method = "kendall")
cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$z,method = "kendall")
corr.test(alldata,method = "kendall")
```

Gives me the following:

```
> cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$y,method = "kendall")

    Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  alldata$x and alldata$y
T = 30, p-value = 0.2164
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.3333333 

> cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$z,method = "kendall")

    Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  alldata$x and alldata$z
T = 36, p-value = 0.01667
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
tau 
0.6 

> corr.test(alldata,method = "kendall")
Call:corr.test(x = alldata, method = "kendall")
Correlation matrix 
     x    y    z
x 1.00 0.33 0.60
y 0.33 1.00 0.02
z 0.60 0.02 1.00
Sample Size 
[1] 10
Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
     x    y    z
x 0.00 0.69 0.20
y 0.35 0.00 0.95
z 0.07 0.95 0.00

 To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

As you can see, the (uncorrected) p-values in the lower half of the matrix generated by the corr.test function do not match the ones from the cor.test function. If I do the same using Spearman (or Pearson), things do add up:

```
cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$y,method = "spearman")
cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$z,method = "spearman")
corr.test(alldata,method = "spearman")
```

Gives me:

```
> cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$y,method = "spearman")

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  alldata$x and alldata$y
S = 110, p-value = 0.3488
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.3333333 

> cor.test(alldata$x,alldata$z,method = "spearman")

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  alldata$x and alldata$z
S = 90, p-value = 0.1909
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.4545455 

> corr.test(alldata,method = "spearman")
Call:corr.test(x = alldata, method = "spearman")
Correlation matrix 
     x     y     z
x 1.00  0.33  0.45
y 0.33  1.00 -0.09
z 0.45 -0.09  1.00
Sample Size 
[1] 10
Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
     x    y    z
x 0.00 0.69 0.56
y 0.35 0.00 0.80
z 0.19 0.80 0.00

 To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: From `help("cor.test")`: "For Kendall's test, by default (if exact is NULL), an exact p-value is computed if there are less than 50 paired samples containing finite values and there are no ties. Otherwise, the test statistic is the estimate scaled to zero mean and unit variance, and is approximately normally distributed." `corr.test` does not compute exact p-values for small samples but uses a t statistics. That also doesn't appear to be the same approach `cor.test` uses for larger samples.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the difference. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other method to estimate the p-value? So either the t statistic from the corr.test function, or the estimate from the cor.test function?